# UITableView has inconsistent width

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, autoresizingmask

I have two `UITableView` and both are displayed side by side. There's also a `UITextView` at the right-most side of the view.

So the first `UITableView` with a width of 300px is at the left-most side. The second `UITableView` is at the center of the view. This table has a width of 150px. Then the `UITextView`, which has a dynamic width (since there are different widths for different orientations), which as I've mentioned before is at the right-most side.

The problem is the 2 `UITableViews` differ in sizes depending on the orientation.

This is how I initialize them:

```
UITableView *bookTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 102, 300, self.view.bounds.size.height - 102)];
[bookTable setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];

UITableView *pageTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(bookTable.bounds.size.width, 102, 150, self.view.bounds.size.height - 102)];
[pageTable setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];

UITextView *notesView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((bookTable.bounds.size.width + pageTable.bounds.size.width), 102, self.view.bounds.size.width - (bookTable.bounds.size.width + pageTable.bounds.size.width), self.view.bounds.size.height - 102)];
[notesView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
```

As you can see, I set up the `autoresizingMask` on each of them. What's happening is that 
bookTable's portrait width is 300px, but when I turn to landscape, the width becomes 400px.

Is the `autoresizingMask` responsible for this? If so how should I remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem like this. You might need to post some more code, but you should use 'UITableViewDataSource' method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This way you can add your textfields to the cells subview and then set the autoresizing.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];            
[cell setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
```